# Conky Infinity for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, themes, conky

Is the conky infinity theme available for 16.04? I have literally tried everything. All of the methods refer to the previous versions. Is it still available? Also if possible, can you provide with the script and procedure for installation? Thanks.

[image: Conky for a previous version]

Comment: Surely it works on 16.04. Just copy the conky files and run conky.